# How to collect code coverage for spawned sub-processes using Jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, istanbul, nyc

I am writing integration tests for a CLI. All the unit tests are written using Jest as out-of-the-box it produces code coverage without any configuration, but unfortunately it does not instrument sub-processes, for example executed via Node's spawn and fork commands.

I have tried to introduce nyc into the mix as suggested in [this comment on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3190#issuecomment-354758036) however it has not worked for me.

I have played with various configurations (based on the initial aforementioned suggestion and also ideas from these issues: [1](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5274), [2](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/729)), however either I get no coverage statistics at all or only coverage for my unit tests, not the integration tests that spawn sub-processes.

The relevant parts of my `package.json` which configures nyc and Jest:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc --clean jest --coverage",
},
"jest": {
  "verbose": true,
  "testURL": "http://localhost/",
  "globalSetup": "./jest.setup.js",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "collectCoverage": false
},
"nyc": {
  "include": [
    "packages/*/src/**/*.js"
  ],
  "reporter": [
    "html"
  ]
},
```

I am using [`execa`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa) to run the sub-processes and do so as follows:

```
await execa("nyc --reporter none node", args);
```

Comment: Looks like you have `"collectCoverage": false`, but the linked Github comment says to use `"collectCoverage": true, "coverageReporters": [ "none" ]`